# How to apply group policy?

Tags: samba, active-directory

I have a windows server and all the clients are linux based(ubuntu 11.10),i want to set up group/domain policy on my network.

Please suggest anything other than likewise-open policy. How to apply group policy in local machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LDAP Authentication for setting users and policies for those users,

For more information check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer)

you can provide group policy in local machine using LDAP authentication

Answer (score 1):

You really need a third party solution to apply Win GPs to an Ubuntu system.  Free solutions like Likewise Open and Centrify Express will apply the domain policies (e.g. enforce password policies, like after X invalid attempts lock out the AD account), but if you want a solution that for example does Gnome desktop configuration, you will need to go with a commercial solution such as Centrify DirectControl that can do Linux desktop lockdown via GPOs just like you would lock down a Windows desktop using GPOs, e.g. http://www.centrify.com/directcontrol/group-policy-for-linux-desktops.asp

Hope this helps

JS