# Equivalent to Windows Group Policies (GPO) in Ubuntu

Tags: server, active-directory

I am trying to apply GPO for client Ubuntu machines in a centralized way.

Is it possible to apply GPO in ubuntu 10.04 ( other than using likewise Enterprise)? Until now my client machines have been able to login with with my windows domain/username with the help of LIKEWISE-OPEN .

But I want to restrict my client machines via GROUP POLICY . Is this possible without using the commercial packages, e.g., LIKEWISE-ENTERPRISE and Centrify?

Comment: I'm guessing you've gotten your answer to this within the past 6 years already, no?

Answer (score -2):

this is kind of what LDAP is for, and there was another question on this topic a while back: [How to apply group policy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90972/how-to-apply-group-policy)

Comment: thanx,, :) but i am able to join my machine to Windows Domain with LIKEWISE-open but I don't know is this possible to add those machine to group policy manager or not..? because I do not want to go for the payble packages eg LIKEWISE-ENTERPRISE and Centrify..